# Extracting areal precipitation from multiple location from large netcdf files

Tags: python, r, bigdata, netcdf4

I have huge netcdf files, storing precipitation data for whole Germany with 1 km spatial and 5 min temporal resolution. I have 372 equidistant points across the country where the areal precipitation needs to be calculated within a circular area around these point with different radii (2km, 4km, 6km, 8km, ..., 18 km).
The files are saved in daily resolutions and extracting what I need takes a long time.
I have 22 years of data in daily files, and I need get the areal averages for 10 area sizes. So this needs to be repeated 22*10*365 = 80300 iterations. I ran the following code only for `point.x.y[1:10,]` and it tool over 15 minutes. Even with paralel processing this calculation will take months. Is there any efficient way of doing this?

I have tried brick() and extract() in R and xarray in Python.

```
nc.flname  = paste0(ncPath, "xxx.nc")
nc = nc_open(nc.flname)

lat_nc <- ncvar_get(nc, "lat")
lon_nc <- ncvar_get(nc, "lon")
x_nc = ncvar_get(nc, "x")
y_nc = ncvar_get(nc, "y")

Points_LatLon = read.csv(paste0(PointsPath, "StudyPoints_372_LatLon.csv"))
## This is necessary because the nc files's dimensions are not directly lat
### - lon. I find the closest cell of the grid to my desired point by 
## calculating the distance
points.row.cols = sapply(1:nrow(Points_LatLon), function(p){
  ind = (find_the_closest_pixel_ind(Points_LatLon$longitude[p], 
                                    Points_LatLon$latitude[p],
                                    lon_nc, lat_nc))
  row.col = which(lat_nc == lat_nc[ind] & lon_nc == lon_nc[ind], arr.ind = T)
  return(row.col)
})

point.x.y = cbind(x = x_nc[points.row.cols[1,]], y = y_nc[points.row.cols[2,]])

rainfall.brick = brick(nc.flname, varname ='RR') 
time_series <- extract(rainfall.brick, point.x.y, buffer = 2000, fun = mean)
```

I'd appreciate any solution in R, Python and/or a combination with ArcMap.

Comment: Hi and welcome GolGosh! Stack Overflow works best when *you* provide code from which we can help troubleshoot. Asking for a solution with minimal effort and no starting point reduces your chance of getting the help you need. You will likely get better, faster help if you edit your question to include a reproducible sample dataset, the code and what specifically isn't working about your code, as well as your desired output.  Good luck!

Comment: @jpsmith Thank you for the tip. I thought my question was clear enough. I edited it.

Comment: no worries, just trying to help and make sure you get the help you need! Good luck!

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)